# On the weak star continuity of ODE solution operators.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Looking at following ODE:

$$\dot{x}(t) = f(t, x(t),u(t)) \; \text{ s.t. } \; x(t_0) = x_0, \tag{IVP}\label{IVP}$$

s.t. $u \in L^{\infty}(I, \mathbb{R}^m)$ and $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an interval. I wonder under which conditions it's possible
to formulate the existence of a sequentially weak* continuous operator $\psi$ on
$L^{\infty}(I, \mathbb{R}^m)$ s.t. $\psi (u)$ is a solution to \eqref{IVP}.

I have the feeling this should be well known theory, unfortunately I never did ODE theory, I would also be happy with a book reference.